# What is a magnetic flux rope and how does it differ from magnetic flux tubes?

Tags: sun, solar-system, magnetohydrodynamics

I am currently taking a course on solar physics and it appears the terminology in solar physics is either needlessly verbose or I am just missing something.  What is a flux rope and what is a flux tube?  How are they different?

I know this is a (very) basic question but there isn't a great deal of documentation from what I can tell.  Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S.  Is it fair to say that the differential rotation is the cause of all of the effects within solar physics ultimately?

E.g. the twisting of a magnetic loop ultimately leading to a CME.  Is this twisting from the differential rotation or from the influence of the current in the loop upon itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a basic question and the answer is very messy.  Well, a flux tube is relatively easy to define.  You can just think of it as an isosurface of constant magnetic flux.  A flux rope, however, is another beast.  I have asked colleagues of mine what their definition of a flux rope was and I get a different answer from everyone that I ask...

Comment: Yeah a flux tube is fine, absolutely.  Flux rope...  well at least now I know ropes and tubes are different things.  I was starting to worry heliophysicists were just being needlessly verbose or full of english graduates!

Do you have a "hand wavy" explanation at least to satisfy me?  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, technically they could be the same thing in some contexts.  However, I would generally associated a flux rope with a prominence or filament erupting from the sun.  I think some people would define a flux rope as a force-free flux tube (e.g., $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} = 0$).  Though as I said before, flux ropes are like substorms in that they do not have a single objective definition (at least not that I know of).

Answer (score 3):

The difference lies in the topology of the magnetic field. While a flux tube involves, as honeste_vivere pointed out, a region in space with constant magnetic flux, a flux rope involved a twisted magnetic field line that contains (from Ampere's law) a flowing current.

In that sense, flux tubes are a theoretical concept used to study the transport of plasma within large structures such as magnetospheres, while flux ropes are more like physical entities that store magnetic energy that can, eventually, be released in the form of an eruption (although, as far as I know, the origin of CMEs is still debated).

Answer (score 0):

A flux rope involves some twisting, and so has the nice physical interpretation of a current flowing along the magnetic field. The limiting case would be a flux tube with no twist within it; this is not very physical but looks like what we often see in solar images.

Answer (score 0):

Flux tubes are isolated concentrations of magnetic field found in the solar convection zone. There have been various studies with untwisted magnetic flux tubes with not much success. For a flux tube to rise from the convection zone, thus leading to formation of sunspots, it requires that the flux tube is twisted. 
Flux ropes, on the other hand, are long outstretched series of magnetic field loops as observed on the solar corona.